# Connect to postgres database which is in a docker

Tags: docker, pgadmin

I am having trouble connecting via pgAdmin to a postgresql database, which is in a docker compose container.

In docker compose I run 3 images, one an nginx server, another a laravel server and finally postgrest. But from outside of docker composer, I can't connect with pgAdmin, if the laravel server can connect with the db.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    webserver:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: webserver
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            - php
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./Dockerfiles/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        networks:
            app-network:
    php:
        build:
            context: Dockerfiles/php
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: backend
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./Dockerfiles/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

        networks:
            app-network:
    database:
        image: postgres:latest
        container_name: postgres-db
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: pg-db
        ports:
            - "5435:5432"
        volumes:
            - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            # add entrypoint script to init db
            - ./Dockerfiles/postgres/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        networks:
            app-network:
networks:
    app-network:
volumes:
    app-data:
    postgres-data:
```

this is the pgAdmin server config:

[image]

But I get this pgAdmin output:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not connect to server: connection refused. Is the server running
> on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: is pg admin running as a docker container ?

Comment: @DefSoudani not it is not running as docker container? it's necesary?

Comment: @JAOdev no, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You might have a typo in you compose file:

```
 ports:
   - "5435:5432"
```

you are forwarding the postgres container 5432 port to your host 5435 port. So either change this to 5432:5432 or with pgadmin running on your host machine connect to the 5435 port.